# Istio EnvoyFilter HTTP_ROUTE example

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

I try to write EnvoyFilter for the `istio-ingressgateway` routes:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: retry
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      istio: ingressgateway
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: HTTP_ROUTE
      match:
        context: GATEWAY
        routeConfiguration:
          vhost:
            name: '*.example.net:8000'
            route:
              name: 'cfs'
    
      patch:
        operation: MERGE
        value:
          typed_config:
            '@type': type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.route.v3.Route
            route:
              cluster_not_found_response_code: NOT_FOUND
```

This filter is not working, where did I make a mistake?

Istio v1.9.3

---

I expect `cluster_not_found_response_code: NOT_FOUND` to appear in this configuration:

```
$ istioctl proxy-config route istio-ingressgateway-5abc45c5cb-44l47.istio-system -o json
```

```yaml
[
    {
        "name": "http.8000",
        "virtualHosts": [
            {
                "name": "*.example.net:8000",
                "domains": [
                    "*.example.net",
                    "*.example.net:8000"
                ],
                "routes": [
                    {
                        "name": "cfs",
                        "match": {
                            "prefix": "/upload",
                            "caseSensitive": true
                        },
                        "route": {
                            "cluster": "outbound|8000||cfs.default.svc.cluster.local",
                            "timeout": "0s",
                            "retryPolicy": {
                                "retryOn": "retriable-status-codes,connect-failure,reset",
                                "numRetries": 4,
                                "retryPriority": {
                                    "name": "envoy.retry_priorities.previous_priorities",
                                    "typedConfig": {
                                        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.retry.previous_priorities.PreviousPrioritiesConfig",
                                        "updateFrequency": 2
                                    }
                                },
                                "retryHostPredicate": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "envoy.retry_host_predicates.previous_hosts"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "hostSelectionRetryMaxAttempts": "5",
                                "retriableStatusCodes": [
                                    404
                                ]
                            },
                            "cors": {
                                "allowOriginStringMatch": [
                                    {
                                        "exact": "*"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "allowMethods": "GET,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS",
                                "allowHeaders": "Content-Type,Content-Disposition,Origin,Accept",
                                "maxAge": "86400",
                                "allowCredentials": false,
                                "filterEnabled": {
                                    "defaultValue": {
                                        "numerator": 100
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "maxStreamDuration": {
                                "maxStreamDuration": "0s"
                            }
                        },
                        "metadata": {
                            "filterMetadata": {
                                "istio": {
                                    "config": "/apis/networking.istio.io/v1alpha3/namespaces/default/virtual-service/cara"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "decorator": {
                            "operation": "cfs.default.svc.cluster.local:8000/upload*"
                        },
                        "responseHeadersToRemove": [
                            "x-envoy-upstream-service-time"
                        ]
                    },
                    ...
                ],
                "includeRequestAttemptCount": true
            },
            ...
        ],
        "validateClusters": false
    },
    ...
]
```

Unable to change any route configuration value `cluster_not_found_response_code` is just an example.

Comment: Hello @Jonas, you need to provide more information. What do you want to achive? How did you set up your cluster? What configuration did you use? What exactly did you do? Filter is not working - do you have any error? Any logs?

Comment: The filter is accepted and created. If you could check my filter on your cluster or write your own working filter for HTTP_ROUTE. I need to know should I report Istio issue or keep searching for an issue in my filter. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

On my environment , the given EnvoyFilter definition does not pass the schema validation at the CRD level:

```
CRD validation error while creating EnvoyFilter resource:
Warning:  Envoy filter: unknown field "typed_config"  in envoy.config.route.v3.Route
envoyfilter.networking.istio.io/retry-faulty created
```

Seems like there is  no such Envoy type in V3 api like [Route](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/f3f8df1ce02bf213ad01204e7b024c4532e0ecdd/api/envoy/config/route/v3/route.proto#L25).

---

**Workaround:**
You may try to specific a direct response on VirtualService level, like in [this github issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/29264):
This works fine for me:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: retry-faulty
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      istio: ingressgateway
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: HTTP_ROUTE
      match:
        context: GATEWAY
        routeConfiguration:
          vhost:
            name: 'productpage.com:80'
            route:
              name: 'http.80'
      patch:
        operation: MERGE
        value:
          typed_config:
            "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.route.v3.RouteConfiguration
            route:
              cluster_not_found_response_code: NOT_FOUND
```

Response headers from istio:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
content-length: 9
content-type: text/plain
date: Fri, 11 Jun 2021 12:46:01 GMT
server: istio-envoy
```